# Can not access website

Tags: laravel, web

I have a problem that when I access the homepage of website and other subpages of it, it is normal. But when I type manually the subpages such as "example.com/blog" into URL bar, it shows error that lost the "/", it becomes "example.comblog" and of course it causes error.

[image: enter link description here]

Please help me.

Comment: Did you write / paste some really weird `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: Remove your dns cache and run again

Comment: I have tried on a new computer and it still causes error. Do you think it relates to configuration in Laravel?

Comment: Can you show your webserver configuration?

Comment: I only take the DNS configuration by cloudflare. Hosting and source code is taken by another person. So I don't have information about it @Jerodev